# NSTableView data source editing

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-snow-leopard, nstableview, nsbuttoncell

I'm just a beginner in Cocoa developing for Snow Leopard and I have problem with editing values in data array that displayed in `NSTableView`.

I tried to edit some property of my object in `-tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row:`  and I have `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` after this.

My `NSTableView` contains one column with `NSButtonCell` cells and this column have identifier 'checked'.

My code is simple and looks like this:

```js
@interface MyObj: NSObject {
    BOOL checked;
}
@property (assign) BOOL checked;
@end
```

```js
@imlpementation MyObj
@synthesize checked;
@end
```

```js
@interface MyAppDelegate: NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource> {
    NSMutableArray *data;
    NSTableView *table;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSTableView *table;
- (NSInteger) numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView;
- (id) tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex;
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView setObjectValue:(id)anObject forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex;

@end
```

```js
@implementation MyAppDelegate

@synthesize table;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    data = [[NSMutableArray array] retain];

        // some code that add few objects to data
        // each object is instance of MyObj and I call alloc+init+retain for each
        // ...

    [table reloadData];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [data release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView {
    return (data == nil ? 0 : [data count]);
}

- (id) tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex {
    MyObj *obj;
    obj = [data objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
    NSString *identifier;
    identifier = [aTableColumn identifier];
    return [obj performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(identifier)];
}

- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView setObjectValue:(id)anObject forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex {
    MyObj *obj;
    obj = [data objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
    NSString *identifier;
    identifier = [aTableColumn identifier];
    if ([identifier isEqualTo:@"checked"]) {
        BOOL value = [anObject boolValue];
        obj.checked = value;
        [data replaceObjectAtIndex:rowIndex withObject:obj];
    }

    [table reloadData];
}

@end
```

And I have raised `objc_msgSend_vtable5` from `-[NSButtonCell setObjectValue]` method.

Comment: On which line did you get the error? Also, given that `MyObj` is apparently mutable – you set the `checked` property of one – you shouldn't need to replace it in the `data` array. You've modified the one that's already in `data`. (On a separate subject, I'd recommend `[obj valueForKey:identifier]` instead of `[obj performSelector:NSSelectorFromString(identifier)]`.)

Comment: I have got error after `-tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row:` processed. I use replace object in array only just for possible to fix this error. It is not works. :)

Comment: This `-[NSButtonCell setObjectValue]` method runs by Cocoa framework after `-tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row:` ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution for my problem. I changed `BOOL checked` to `NSNumber *checked`.

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView setObjectValue:(id)anObject forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex {
    MyObj *obj = (MyObj *)[data objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
    NSString *identifier;
    identifier = [aTableColumn identifier];

    if ([identifier isEqualTo:@"checked"]) {
        [obj setValue:[[NSNumber numberWithBool:[anObject boolValue]] retain] forKey:[aTableColumn identifier]];
    }

    [table reloadData];
}
```

And all works fine right now. I hope it helps someone.

Comment: My tableView:setObjectValue... method isn't getting called at all.  I found a comment in Apple's headers that says that this method is only called for cell-based table views, and not for view-based table views.  I understand that cell-based table views are deprecated.  I do want to use view-based table views, but I'm not sure what to do to make my table views editable.